# Connected $G_\delta$ sets in a connected completely metrizable space with more than one point.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Suppose $(X,\tau)$ is a connected completely metrizable space with more than one point.  Let $\mathbb{G}$ be the set of all connected  $G_\delta$ subsets of $X$. And let $\mathbb{O}$ be the class of connected open subsets of $X$.

(1) Is it possible that $\mathbb{G}$ is finite? 
(2) Can $\mathbb{O}$ be finite?

Comment: For (2) I'd look at some nontrivial continua, like pseudo-arc. I think the pseudo-arc is an example, but I have only very cursory knowledge of continuum theory, so I won't post that as an answer...

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ has at least two points then $X$ is uncountable and since every singleton $\{x\}$ is an $G_{\delta }$ set and connected then $\mathbb{G}$ must be infinite.